# Eclipse 4 RCP Can you add an Activator to an existing project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How does one generate and add an Activator class to an existing Eclipse RCP project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any plugin project including the main RCP project you can create the Activator from the Overview tab of the MANIFEST.MF editor.

Click the 'Activator' link at the left of the activator field to open the create class dialog.

A basic Activator just implements the `org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator` interface.

An Activator for a 3.x compatibility mode UI plugin can extend `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin`